# Jmeter : Print Thread properties in SMTP message body

Tags: jmeter

In Message body, I want to display content like

Threads : 1
Rampup : 1
Loop : 2
Duration : 10 seconds

How could we print all the properties of thread in mail body?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values dynamically in the runtime by calling the relevant [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class methods from the [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) like:

- Threads: `${__groovy(ctx.getThreadGroup().getPropertyAsString('ThreadGroup.num_threads'),)}`
- Ramp Up: `${__groovy(ctx.getThreadGroup().getPropertyAsString('ThreadGroup.ramp_time'),)}`
- Loops: `${__groovy(ctx.getThreadGroup().getSamplerController().getPropertyAsString('LoopController.loops'),)}`

Demo:

1. Assuming the following Thread Group definition:

   [image]
2. You can get the required information with __groovy() function:

   [image]

The function can be used literally anywhere in your script, for example in the SMTP Samplers message input field

Answer (score -1):

You can enter text and [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions) in to message body:

1. Add [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler)
2. Set up email settings: mail server host, port, login, password,..
3. Set up message body, use text and variables, for example:

   `Thread: ${__threadNum}.`